# Document-modal JFileChooser?

Tags: java, swing, file-io

After reading the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) I don't see a good way to make the dialog modal while using [showDialog()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#showDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.String-).

Is there a good way to make a JFileChooser instance document-modal instead of application-modal?

Comment: Before you go too deep into this please read about the current Swing implementation of document modality. It's really weird and it doesn't work as one would expect. Every new document modal dialogue blocks the previous ones and the code after setVisibleTrue() of each dialogue will only run after the last dialogue was closed. You can try with a simple small demo app with 3 dialogues.

Comment: You can find a sample here: http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6525366

Comment: Excellent point @Vlad - I had forgotten about that.  So I can't use `showDialog` with a document-modal dialog.  Instead, for threading reasons I'd need to have a listener react to an event.

Comment: What threading issues? That statement scares me...

Comment: Please see @Vlad's comments above which include a link to the Oracle bug database describing this complex issue in detail.  I'll say here that it pertains to cases involving multiple modal dialogs being closed in an order other than the reverse order in which they were presented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
JFileChooser instance = new JFileChooser()
{
    protected JDialog createDialog(Component parent) throws HeadlessException
    {
        JDialog dialog = super.createDialog(parent);
        dialog.setModalityType(ModalityType.DOCUMENT_MODAL);
        return dialog;
    }
};
instance.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if (JFileChooser.APPROVE_SELECTION.equals(e.getActionCommand()))
        {
            File file = ((JFileChooser)e.getSource()).getSelectedFile();
            //loadFromFile(file); // My custom function for loading from a File
        }
    }
});
instance.showOpenDialog(this);
```